# Split multiline string and append to a new list

Tags: python

I have a csv file which has a set of records. One of the columns is a multiline string. I need to split these lines and duplicate the main list. For example, if the file contains the following records.

```
Row 1 - John, 2501, Admin/Partner/HR, TX
Row 2 - Max, 3489, Accountant/Admin/HR, MN
```

where `Admin/Partner/HR` and `Accountant/Admin/HR` are multiline strings.
I need the output as below:

```
Row 1 - John, 2501, Admin, TX
Row 2 - John, 2501, Partner, TX
Row 3 - John, 2501, HR, TX
Row 4 - Max, 3489, Accountant, MN
Row 5 - Max, 3489, Admin, MN
Row 6 - Max, 3489, HR, MN
```

I tried the following function

```
def splitrows(list_old,col):
  count = 0;
  array_new = []
  for row in list_old:
    splitArray = []
    splitarray = row[col].split('\n\n')
    if(len(splitarray)>0):
      for eachLine in splitarray:
        row[col] = eachLine
        array_new.append(row)


  return array_new
```

If I use append, only the last row gets repeated. If I use array_new+=row, then each column is split and added to the list but I don't want this to happen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's your expected output if the input is `Row 1 - John, 2501/2502/2503, Admin/Partner/HR, TX`  ?

Comment: First, but well-asked question! Welcome on board :-)

Comment: @ Avinash, I wanted to split based on just the third column..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Reut Sharabani's answer is better as far as using the csv library is much cleaner than trying to roll your own.  With that said, I'd also like to explain why you're seeing what you're seeing.

First off, you have a bogus line that had me concerned you had a case issue... `splitArray = []` creates an empty array named `splitArray`; your next line creates a new array named `splitarray` and in python, that's a completely different variable.

More importantly, when you do `row[col] = eachLine` it changes the row value and then when you append it, it really only appends a reference to `row` and not a copy, such that when you change `row`, you change it for each version you appended to your `array_new`.  The easiest way to fix this (which is also what Reut's answer is doing) is to do:

```
def splitrows(list_old,col):
  count = 0;
  array_new = []
  for row in list_old:
    splitarray = row[col].split('\n\n')
    if(len(splitarray)>0):
      for eachLine in splitarray:
        newrow = row[:] # create a copy of the row
        newrow[col] = eachLine
        array_new.append(newrow)


  return array_new
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove (or at least to comment(-out)) the *bogus line*?

Comment: The fist line of your code snippet is still somewhat confusing. the statements `count = 0;   array_new = []   for row in list_old:` are on the same line as the controlling loop. Is this intended/necessary?

Comment: Sorry, I [couldn't wait](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7468456)

Comment: That's fine; I was originally going to just include the bit inside the for loop but decided to include the full program with the change to be clearer where I changed (it'd be nice if there was a way to color this).  Also, I would have though that row[col].split('\\') would have made more sense given what he provided as inputs (i.e. split on an \ (which requires 2 slashes due to escaping) instead of splitting on two newlines, which might just be an artifact of pasting in the code)

Answer (score 2):

Since what you're parsing is (almost) a [csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). You could use the [`csv module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open("test.csv") as f:
    # create a reader
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # create a new row for each item in column 2
        for item in row[2].split('/'):
            # align items
            row[2] = ' ' + item.lstrip()
            print ','.join(row)
```

Output:

```
John, 2501, Admin, TX
John, 2501, Partner, TX
John, 2501, HR, TX
Max, 3489, Accountant, MN
Max, 3489, Admin, MN
Max, 3489, HR, MN
```

Comment: Could it be that the `Row %d - ` part was only for illustrating purposes? (it's the [*two splits*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46btEgKmCTo) which seemed suspicious to me)

Comment: Could be. If so - it's even easier.

Answer (score 0):

Algo:

1. Use `csv` module to read and write csv file.
2. Read input file and Open output file in write mode.
3. Iterate every row from the Input file.
4. If second item from row contains `/` i.e. multiple values the do `step 5,6,7` and If not then do `step 8`.
5. Split string by `split()` method.
6. Iterate every split value by `for` loop.
7. Create new row according to split value and write into output file.
8. Write row into output file.

**Input:** input.csv

```
John, 2501, Admin/Partner/HR, TX
Max, 3489, Accountant/Admin/HR, MN
```

**Code:**

```
import csv

input_file = "input.csv"
output_file = "output.csv"

#- Open File and read by csv module.
with open(input_file, ) as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp)
    #- Open File in write mode and write by csv module.
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as fp2:
        writer_root = csv.writer(fp2, delimiter=',')

        #- Iterate every row form the Input file.
        for row in root:
            #- check if second item from row contains / i.e. multiple values.
            if "/" in row[2]:
                #- Split by /
                tmp = row[2].split("/")
                for i in tmp:
                    new_row = [row[0], row[1], i, row[3]]
                    print "Debug 1: ", new_row
                    #- Write Row in New file.
                    writer_root.writerow(new_row)
            else:
                    writer_root.writerow(row)
```

**Output:**

**Debug statements:**

```
$ python 5.py 
Debug 1:  ['John', ' 2501', ' Admin', ' TX']
Debug 1:  ['John', ' 2501', 'Partner', ' TX']
Debug 1:  ['John', ' 2501', 'HR', ' TX']
Debug 1:  ['Max', ' 3489', ' Accountant', ' MN']
Debug 1:  ['Max', ' 3489', 'Admin', ' MN']
Debug 1:  ['Max', ' 3489', 'HR', ' MN']
```

**Output File:** output.csv

```
John, 2501, Admin, TX
John, 2501,Partner, TX
John, 2501,HR, TX
Max, 3489, Accountant, MN
Max, 3489,Admin, MN
Max, 3489,HR, MN
```